# Help translate these two sentences with 也未必 and 更何况

Tags: translation, preposition

1. 有时就连你的父亲也未必信得过，更何况是陌生人。
2. 有时连陌生人你也可以相信，更何况是你的父亲。

The challenging parts for me are `也未必` and `连…更何况`.

Comment: 未必 = not necessarily; 连…更何况 = even ..., much less ... Does that give you a clue?

Comment: Actually I think it should be 连 ... 也 together, which means "even ... also". Does that help you? OR perhaps it's what @StumpyJoePete said :P I'm not sure!

Comment: 1. Sometimes even your father is not necessarily trustworthy, much less strangers. 2. Sometimes even even strangers are trustworthy, *let alone* your father. ([ref](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29878/the-phrase-let-alone)).

Comment: For sentence #2, i don't think `much less` fits there (maybe `much more`, if it exists). Is there something else to replace `let alone`?

Comment: @Ming The whole construction is something like "连 NP 也 VP, 更何况 NP VP". The 也 is part of it, but it's connected to the first of the two clauses. Jeff: That's a good observation about how "much less" works. I honestly can't think of a good-sounding translation for #2 ("let alone" sounds weird to me and "much more" isn't a real phrase).

Comment: @StumpyJoePete ahh I see, thanks for that :) "let alone" is perfect here though, that's how I read it in my mind.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete How about 'not to mention/not to say'?

Comment: @NS.X. Good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 有时就连你的父亲也未必信得过，更何况是陌生人。

Sometimes you can't even trust your father, not to mention a stranger.

> 有时连陌生人你也可以相信，更何况是你的父亲。

Sometimes you can even trust a stranger, not to mention your father.

I think `even...not to mention` would be a proper translation for `连...更何况`, `也未必` is just a word indicate that the sentence is negative.

Comment: how is 過used in the first example？

Comment: @davidtingsu According to Pleco dictionary, it is used after 得 and means "deserving". So in this case it means "it deserves the trust" or "can trust enough".